# Matrices in libgdx for 2d

Tags: java, matrix, libgdx

I have a layer that holds many sprites. Sprites are performing their own movements within the layer. I would like to apply transformations to the group. Naturally, its children need to perform the same adjustment.

I think I'm looking for a matrix, and libgdx does seem to have them. But I don't understand how I can apply it to my libgdx sprites. But if that's not what I need, then what do I need?

Comment: Sprites in LibGDX are intended for batching together into a single mesh, so they do not use separate matrices for each of them to modify their transformations. If you want to build an hierarchy of parents and children where you can transform branches of the tree as you described, read up on using scene2d: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d  LibGDX does use matrices for transforming meshes. There are the Matrix3 and Matrix4 classes. But they aren't useful with the Sprite class.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've explored Scene2d and it does a lot of what I want. However, there's quite a bit of overhead switching everything over. This is something I want to do in the future, but for now I need a quick fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from what I can tell, theres no easy solution here (although, I dont have access to libgdx right now, so I havent tested anything).

If all you need to do is keep track of translations, it might be easiest to give your layer a location (vector2 or otherwise), and when calculating the location for your sprites, offset them by the location of the layer.

If you need access to all the transformations (rotation, scale, etc.), it's probably best to use a [matrix3](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix3.html). matrix3s allow you to append any number of transformations (via translate, scale, rotate, etc), and then multiply your location  by the matrix, in order to apply those transformations.

So for instance, if you were using a Sprite object called 'object', your code might look something like.

```
    Matrix3 mat3 = new Matrix3();
    //do your transformations
    Vector2 vec2 = new Vector2(object.getX(), object.getY());
    vec2.mul(mat3);
    object.setPosition(vec2.x, vec2.y);
```

Note that the vector multiply function changes the original vector, so if you are using a Vector2 to store your location, you probably want to create a copy of it before you apply the transformations